# remove multi charachter in sentence (angular 9)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this json reponse :

```
id: 30
tableName: "UserCredit"
keyValues: "{"Id":39}"
oldValues: "{"CoinLastUpdate":"2020-02-18T14:18:13.5155426+00:00","ScoreLastUpdate":"2020-02-18T14:18:13.5155429+00:00"}"
newValues: "{"CoinLastUpdate":"2020-02-18T14:18:15.7325823+00:00","ScoreLastUpdate":"2020-02-18T14:18:15.7325826+00:00"}"
auditType: "Update"
createdOnUtc: "2020-02-18T14:18:15.7338989Z"
createdByRefId: 39
```

I want to find the difference between `oldValues` and `newValues` then I write this code :

```
setOldNewValue(item: DeiffrentModel): void {
let oldValue;
let newValue;
console.log(item.oldValues)
if (item.newValues !== null) {
  newValue = item.newValues.split(',');
}
if (item.oldValues !== null) {
  oldValue = item.oldValues.split(',');
}
for (let index = 0; index < newValue.length; index++) {
  let addModel = {} as DeifferModel;
  addModel.field = 'id';
  addModel.newValue = newValue[index];
  console.log(oldValue)
  if (oldValue !== undefined) {
    addModel.oldValue = oldValue[index]
  }
  this.differModel.push(addModel);
}
this.findDiffrent = _.difference(newValue, oldValue);
```

}

Now I have this problem :

**** I create in `newValue` and `oldValue` array of value but it shows like this :

0: "CoinLastUpdate":"2020-02-18T14:18:13.5155426+00:00"

1: "ScoreLastUpdate":"2020-02-18T14:18:13.5155429+00:00"}

but I need just `2020-02-18T14:18:13.5155429+00:00`

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: have you tried using `JSON.parse(item.newValues)` instead of `item.newValues.split(',');` ? You would be able to use it as a JSON object.

Comment: @Random i need to convert that item to array

Comment: _“but I need just 2020-02-18T14:18:13.5155429+00:00”_ - and that is exactly why you should _decode_ the JSON you got there, so that you can then access the `CoinLastUpdate` and `ScoreLastUpdate` _properties_ of these objects, to directly and deliberately access these values.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON structure instead of parsing a string manually.
I would also use DeifferModel as a `class` instead of an `interface`, so you can init items more easily:

```
// in a xxx.model.ts file
export class DeifferModel {
  constructor(public field, public newValue, public oldValue) {}
}

// in your component
setOldNewValue(item: DeiffrentModel): void {
  if (item.newValues) {
    newValue = JSON.parse(item.newValues);
  }
  if (item.oldValues) {
    oldValue = JSON.parse(item.oldValues);
  }
  Object.keys(newValue).foreach(key => {
    const addModel = new DeifferModel('id', newValue[key], oldValue[key]);
    this.differModel.push(addModel);
  });
  this.findDiffrent = _.difference(newValue, oldValue); // no use of "this.differModel" ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insteading of storing these as an array, parse the values to an object

```
if (item.newValues !== null) {
  newValue = item.newValues.split(',');
}
if (item.oldValues !== null) {
  oldValue = item.oldValues.split(',');
}
```

to

```
oldValue = JSON.parse(oldValues);
newValue = JSON.parse(newValues);
```

You can find the difference in milliseconds like this:

```
CoinLastUpdateDiff = Math.abs(new Date(newValue.CoinLastUpdate) - new Date(oldValue.CoinLastUpdate));
```